# AJAX добавляю обычный комментарий в код и ничего не работает

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Я не совсем понимаю как такое возможно.. учусь делать отправку формы через php обработчик, чтобы страница не перезагружалась использую ajax пока через alert просто..

Так вот собственно если код выглядит так, то все ок алерт выходит, запрос на почту приходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только добавляю комментарий в код, форма не отправляется и просто перенаправляет на пустую страницу по url php файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом кэш чистил, пробовал через инкогнито к css и js файлам даже версию каждую раз добавляю ?v=1.22

Почему так происходит из-за обычного комментария в коде?

Comment: __Научитесь__ код вставлять текстом, а не картинками. Также научитесь использовать консоль разработчика. И нет - комментарий никак не влияет на ваш код. Значит где-то изменяется что-то еще.

Comment: Консоль ошибок не показывает, пусто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего в вашем случае код минимизируется в одну строку и `//` применяется ко всему коду, который идет дальше т.е. он перестает работать.

Сделал такой вывод из комментария о том, что вас перенаправляет на страницу php (т.е. не работает `e.preventDefault`).

Комментируйте вот так `/* комментарий */`

Тогда при минификации комментарий не будет отключать всё, что стоит после `//`

Comment: Все так... спасибо большое

Comment: Любопытно, что за минификатор **настолько** криво работает?

Comment: При выкладке на хостинг могли быть выкинуты некорректные [переводы строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перевод_строки).

Comment: @Spatz как вариант.